# Prove the Relational Calculus logic equivalence

Tags: predicate-logic, relation-algebra

I encountered this in database subject which I am not able to understand even after lot of efforts.

In relational calculus what do you mean by `¬(∀x)(¬P(x))` ?

As far as I know, `(∀x)(P(x))` means `P(x)` is true for **all** `x`.

`(∀x)(¬P(x))` means `P(x)` is not true for **any** `x` but all other tuples belonging to other tables are TRUE.

`(¬∀x)(¬P(x))` means some of the tuples belonging to other tables are TRUE.

Kindly elaborate. If an example can be given, it will be really nice.

Comment: $(\lnot \forall x) (\lnot P(x))$ means: "there are $P$'s : $(\exists x)P(x)$.

Comment: Example : "not **all** (numbers) are not-Odd" means "**some** (number) is Odd".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA "[Tuple Relational Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple_relational_calculus)", the inspiration for Structured Query Languages in relational databases.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Not at all; the calculus is based on set operations and predicate logic.

Answer (score 1):

$\neg(\forall x)(\neg P(x))$ and $(\neg\forall x)(\neg P(x))$ are equivalent expressions.

Both are read as: "Not for all $x$, $P(x)$ is false".

This is also equivalent to: "For some $x$, $P(x)$ is true"

$$\neg \color{silver}(\forall x\color{silver}{)(}\neg P(x)\color{silver}) \qquad\iff\qquad \color{silver}(\exists x\color{silver}{)(}P(x)\color{silver})$$